# how to assign the number in pandas dataframe for the unique value appearing in the row based on given column

Tags: python, pandas

**Data Frame looks like**

```
Unique Id     Date    
   H1         2/03/2022
   H1         2/03/2022
   H1         2/03/2022
   H1         3/03/2022
   H1         4/03/2022
   H2         9/03/2022
   H2         9/03/2022
   H2         10/03/2022
```

**Expected Data Frame**

```
    Unique Id     Date       Count
   H1         2/03/2022       1
   H1         2/03/2022       1
   H1         2/03/2022       1
   H1         3/03/2022       2
   H1         4/03/2022       3
   H2         9/03/2022       1
   H2         9/03/2022       1
   H2         10/03/2022      2
```

Repetitive dates should be assigned with number 1 , else other should be assigned some other number

tried multiple approaches , please assist

Comment: Added a solution (one liner), does that answer your question?

Comment: What is the criteria of having a count of 3 against 4/3?  while the 10/3 has 2. your question is not clear enough. Can unique dates have a same number? please clarify question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, the primary issue is going to be that you need to treat the date as a date object so that October doesn't get moved ahead of September in your second group.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unique_Id': ['H1', 'H1', 'H1', 'H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H2'],
 'Date': ['2/03/2022',
  '2/03/2022',
  '2/03/2022',
  '3/03/2022',
  '4/03/2022',
  '9/03/2022',
  '9/03/2022',
  '10/03/2022']})
```

Dense Rank

```
df.groupby('Unique_Id')['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).rank(method='dense'))
```

Cat Codes

```
df.groupby('Unique_Id')['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).astype('category').cat.codes+1)
```

Factorize

```
df.groupby('Unique_Id')['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0] + 1)
```